# Firestore Real Time Add with a Limit

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore

I have a Firestore real time chat application and I want to limit it only to 10 messages.

```
this.afs
      .collection<any>('chats')
      .doc(chatId)
      .collection<any>('messages', ref =>
        ref.orderBy('created_date', 'asc').limit(10)
      )
      .snapshotChanges()
      .pipe(
        map(actions =>
          actions.map(a => {
            console.log(a);
            const data = a.payload.doc.data();
            const id = a.payload.doc.id;
            return { id, ...data };
          })
        )
      );
```

The issue is I stop getting my new messages when I reach the limit.
Is there a way to limit the messages and still receive real time updates for any upcoming messages?

Comment: `snapshotChanges()` should fire each time the results in the requested query change. Since you order ascending, this means that if a message is added with a `created_date` within the range of the first 10 items, your `snapshotChanges()` should be getting called again. In most chat apps you'll want to sort descending and get the **latest** 10 messages. In that case, adding a message with a newer `created_date` will cause `snapshotChanges` to be triggered again.

Comment: Changing it to desc works and reversing the action array works, It seems that I just wasn't able to see the new messages due to the ordering. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A `snapshotChanges()` callback fires each time the results in the requested query change.

Since you order *ascending*, this means that if a message is added with a `created_date within` the range of the **first** 10 items, your `snapshotChanges()` should be getting called again. In most chat apps you'll want to sort *descending* and get the **latest** 10 messages. In that case, adding a message with a newer created_date will cause `snapshotChanges` to be triggered again.